# How can i call a function if my varible does not exists?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I tried to call my varible "o" or "" or null or false or "undefined" but its not working. My problem is that i have a chat with a code that says to reload the page by itselfs all 2 seconds but if someone is writing in the textarea then it delets the text. I need a code that says to reload the page every 2 seconds but if someone is writing in the textarea then it should reload just after sending the text. 
You can see the code, if you want to try the code just copy it. But first you have to create a database in your sql named "my_db" and then running the page.

```
<?php
    $hostname_db = "localhost";
    $database_db = "my_db";
    $username_db = "root";
    $password_db = "";
    $db = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    //select db and create table to chat


    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_db", $username_db, $password_db);
    $sql = "use my_db";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatroom`(
    `idmassage` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `massage` text NULL,
    `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idmassage`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=hebrew ";
    $conn->exec($sql);



    //select chatroom from dataase

    mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
    $query_chat = "SELECT massage, `user`, `date` FROM chatroom ORDER BY idmassage ASC";
    $chat = mysql_query($query_chat, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_chat = mysql_fetch_assoc($chat);
    $totalRows_chat = mysql_num_rows($chat);

    //inser new data
    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "chat")) {
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO chatroom (massage) VALUES (%s)",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['massage'], "text"));

      mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $db) or die(mysql_error());

      $insertGoTo = "chatTest.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
    }
    //mysql_close($db);
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #D4CACB;
    }
    .chat {
        width: 60%;
        background-color: #878787;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .chat .massagechat {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
    }
    #chat #massagechat #refresh {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 14px;
    }
    body p {
        position: fixed;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 482px;
        margin-left: 94px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="chat" class="chat">
        <div id="massagechat" class="massagechat">
            <?php do { ?>
            <div id="refresh">
               <p1><?php echo $row_chat['user']." ".$row_chat['date']."</br>"; ?></p1>
               <p2><?php echo $row_chat['massage']; ?></p2>
            </div>
            <?php } while ($row_chat = mysql_fetch_assoc($chat)); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="chat">
                <textarea name="massage"  id="input" placeholder=" "></textarea>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit">
                         <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="chat">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>dddd</p>
    <p><?php echo $row_chat; ?></p>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($chat);
    ?>
    <script>
    $( "div.massagechat" ).scrollTop( 999999*999999);
    </script>
    <script>

    ////////////
    $('textarea').on('keyup',function(){

    var input = $(this);

        if(input.val().length == ""){

    var cacheData;
    var data = $("chat").html();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'chatTest.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data !== cacheData){
                    //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                    cacheData = data;
                    $("#chat").html(data);
                }           
            }
        })
    }, 2000);};})// check every 30000 milliseconds
    </script>
```

Comment: Dont understand what is the problem. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: FYI, `massage` is different than `message`. This is two completly different things...

Comment: I have chat when  uset1 typing before send the message and another user for exmple user2 send a message by user1 the textarea its was cleandHope this course now And it will be possible to help me anyway thanks for all the time

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use the Dreamweaver database code it generates for you. It's something that should have been killed off fifteen years ago. PHP 7 has removed support for `mysql_query`, so you must move on to something better. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) and will make your code a lot more readable as prepared statements are very clean and concise.

Comment: Yes I know it thanks
Anyway I'm in the middle to move the code to mysqli without MySQL
Anyway about the top-end code jq Any ideas how I solve it for this to work as I have explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` function  shouldn't be under **keyup** event of the text-area. You can put it under document ready handler.

Also inside setInterval function check for the text-area value, send request only if it's not blank.

Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        if($('textarea').val().trim()!='') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'chatTest.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data !== cacheData){
                            //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                            cacheData = data;
                            $("#chat").html(data);
                        }           
                    }
                });
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```